# Should a REST API wrapper validate inputs before making a request?

Tags: rest, libraries, api-design

Suppose that the server restricts a JSON field to an enumerated set of values.

e.g. a POST request to `/user` expects an object with a field called `gender` that should only be "male", "female" or "n/a".

Should a wrapper library make sure that the field is set correctly before making the request?

Answer (score 1):

Pro: Makes it possible for the client to quickly reject input that would otherwise require a roundtrip to the server. In some cases this would allow for a much better UX.

Con: You have to keep the libary in sync with the backend, otherwise you could reject some valid input.

With a decent type system you should encode this particular restriction in the library API anyway. I think usually people validate at least basic stuff on the client and let server do further validation, like things that can’t be verified on the client at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design choice - the enum type constraint should be documented in the public API of the server and it's part of its contract.

Clients are forced to obey the contract to make a successful request, but are not required to implement the validation logic. You can safely let the clients fail with "Bad Request" or other 4xx error.

Implementing the validation logic on both sides couples the client and the server - any changes to the validation logic should be implemented on both sides.
If the validation logic is something closer to common sense (e.g. this field should not be empty) it can safely be implemented on both sides.
If the validation logic is something more domain specific, I think it should be kept on the backend side only.

You have to think about the same trade-offs with a wrapping library (which can be looked at as a client of the server API). It depends on what the role of the wrapping library is - if the wrapping library should expose the full API contract of the server - than by all means the validation logic can be duplicated in the wrapping lib - other wise I would keep it to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper-library is the actual client of the REST api and hence has to adhere to both the [architectural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) and protocol imposed constraints. In [his blog post](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) Fielding explained some of the constraints even further. One of them are [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) which states that clients shouldn't assume the API to return a specific type, i.e. some user details in JSON. This is what media-types and content negotiation are actually for.

The definition of a media type may give clients a hint on how to process the data received i.e. like with the [JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7095) or [XML](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6351) based [vCard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) format. As media types define the actual format of some specific document it may contain processing rules like pre-validation requirements or syntax regulations i.e. through XML schema or [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) validation.

One of the basic rules in remote computing is though to never trust inputs received and hence the server should validate the results regardless if the client has done a pre-validation before. Due to the typed resource constraint a true RESTful client will check if the received media type does support pre-validation through its spec and only apply pre-validation if the spec is defining it and also mentions some mechanisms on how to perform it (i.e. through certain schema mechanism).

My personal opinion on this is that if you try to follow the REST architectural approach you shouldn't validate the input unless the media type explicitely supports it. As a client will learn through error responses which fields and values a certain REST endpoint expects and the server hopefully validates the inputs anyway I don't see the necessity to validate it on the client side. As performance considerations are often more important than following the rules and recommendations it is though up to you. Note however, that this may or may not couple the client to the server and hence increase the risk of breaking on server changes more easily. As REST is not a protocol but a design suggestion, it is up to you which route you prefer.